# How to eliminate “Error in as.Date.OtherDate(death) : NAs in foreign function call (arg 4)"

Tags: r

I need to convert persian date to gergorian using ConvCalendar library. the character vector is as follows:

```
str(df$death_date)

 chr [1:286] NA NA NA NA "1399/03/12" NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA "1399/03/25" NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...

death <- OtherDate(day=substr(df$death_date,9,10),
                 month=substr(df$death_date,6,7),
                 year=substr(df$death_date,1,4),
                 calendar="persian")
```

once I go to convert the death into gregorian using  as.Date(death) the following error comes out:

```
Error in as.Date.OtherDate(death) : NAs in foreign function call (arg 4)
```

could anyone please tell me what the wrong is?

Answer (score 0):

Package `ConvCalendar` was archived a long time ago, see [CRAN](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=ConvCalendar):

> Archived on 2018-05-24 as check problems were not corrected despite reminders.

If it is installed from source, the following will work.

```
library(ConvCalendar)

y <- x[!is.na(x)]
y <- as.POSIXlt(y, format = '%Y/%m/%d', origin = '1970-01-01')
pers <- OtherDate(day=y$mday, month=y$mon+1, year=y$year, calendar="persian")
as.Date(pers)
#[1] "0120-06-02" "0120-06-15"
```

**Data**

```
x <- scan(what = character(), text = '
NA NA NA NA "1399/03/12" NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA "1399/03/25" NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
')
```